# Php - Accessing Sessions from Database across different servers

Tags: php, session, raspberry-pi, session-variables

I’m currently creating a system which incorporates 3 Raspberry Pis, each of it acts as a server and each has a different IP address. Each of them has a web application in it, also having a login page. I currently have a central login system, and after I login to it, there will be 3 links to each of the Raspberry Pis.

What I want is my session to be saved after I click a link to one of the Raspberry Pis from the central login system. I created a custom session handler that stores my session in the database. Is there something I need to do so that when I click a link pointing to one of the Raspberry Pis, my session from the central login will be saved and there’s no need for me to log in again?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [Memcached](https://www.memcached.org/)

Comment: Hi, isn't it possible to take the session from the database and use it? Sorry i'm fairly new to this one.